# How to check which version of KVM I am running?

Tags: 12.10, kvm-virtualization, versions

I have installed KVM using the instructions given on the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation). However, when I try to check its version using

```
kvm --version
```

what I get as output is this

```
QEMU emulator version 1.2.0 (qemu-kvm-1.2.0+noroms-0ubuntu2.12.10.5, Debian), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

which I believe is QEMU's version, not KVM's.

I have tried the method given [here](http://nixcraft.com/showthread.php/15210-Find-out-Linux-KVM-virtualization-version-from-shell-prompt), but this does give an output.

I wanted to know what is the correct method to get the version of KVM I am running.

**Specifications:**

- Ubuntu 12.10
- Linux 3.5.0-43-generic

Answer (score 4):

The command you're looking for is:

`dpkg -s qemu-kvm | grep Version`

You can look up the version of any package using `dpkg -s [package name]`

Regarding the KVM, a quick Google search returned it is titled `qemu-kvm`.

Example output (if you're running Debian Jessie):

> **Version: 1:2.1+dfsg-12+deb8u5a**

As an FYI, the `grep` command is case-sensitive by default, which is important because **Version** is upper-case. You can use the parameter `-i` to ignore case.

Answer (score -1):

The kvm version follows the kernel version.

```
uname -r
```

would therefore, in this case give you the correct version.

[Look here for more information](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Downloads)

Comment: If you read the page carefully, you'll notice kernel versions and KVM versions mentioned explicitly and separately. `uname -r` only gives the kernel version.